# Exception thrown by BeginWaitForConnection when reusing a NamedPipeServerStream in .NET 4 after client disconnects

Tags: .net, named-pipes

I'm trying to use `NamedPipeServerStream` to create a named pipe server in .Net 4. I'm using `BeginWaitForConnection` to wait for the connection, so that I can abort the wait if the server is to be shut down.

Everything works well for the first client --- the connection is acknowledged, the data received, and the response sent OK. However, after the client disconnects everything breaks. I'm calling `BeginWaitForConnection` again to wait for a new connection, but this is throwing an `IOException` saying that the "pipe is broken".

How can I wait for a second client on the same pipe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new instance of `NamedPipeServerStream` specifying the same pipe, and call `BeginWaitForConnection` on that.

i.e. Don't try to reuse a `NamedPipeServerStream` object for different clients: one instance should service one client connection/conversation, then be disposed.

See also [Multithreaded NamePipeServer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570653/multithreaded-namepipeserver-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Another method when using a single client/server configuration is to `Disconnect` the pipe stream when the client disconnects to clean up the pipe. This allows reuse of the pipe. When you call `BeginWaitForConnection` again, it will begin accepting connections.

```
while (true) 
{
    pipe.BeginWaitForConnection();
    // read and write to pipe
    // catch exception when client disconnects
    pipe.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: You also have to be careful about not disposing/closing stream readers/writers that you're using with the named pipe stream as they will close the underlying stream and then it cannot be reused.