# Multithreaded, MultiClient NamedPipeServer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, namedpipeserverstream

I was trying to build a multi threaded named pipe server/client. The code base is based on this thread, [Multithreaded NamePipeServer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570653/multithreaded-namepipeserver-in-c-sharp?lq=1)

The real problem is, i need a bi-directional pipe, to write acknowledgement to cleint. For this, in `ProcessClientThread` i tried to create `StreamWriter` using the input `pipeStream` and write to it, but I'm getting "Broken Pipe" exception. The pipe is `PipeDirection.InOut` already.

Any idea?

Comment: You get a broken pipe when the client closed the pipe without waiting for the return message.