# Using a fifo as stdin to a process

Tags: java, linux, pip, stdin, fifo

How can I use a *fifo* to redirect *stdin* for a process?

Using systemd, I am starting a service that will infrequently require commands to be sent via *stdin*. To overcome this, I have tried the following:

```
mkfifo -m 600 cmdline
/usr/bin/cat cmdline | /opt/jdk-18/bin/java ...
```

I am able to run a command using the following.

```
echo -e "this_is_a_command\n" > cmdline
```

The problem I am having is that this only seems to work for a single command. After running this command once, all other calls to write into the fifo seem to just hang, and the server never process anything else.

How can I use a *fifo* to redirect input to stdin of a daemon process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a named pipe able to do what i want to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093954/is-a-named-pipe-able-to-do-what-i-want-to-do)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `java -jar your-service.jar < cmdline`? It might be better to use a socket

Comment: @stark - Unfortunately this is a precompiled application, and I do not have access to the source - this is the reason I am trying to do it in this way.

Comment: @g00se - I tried this method, and bash seems to never even run the _java_ binary, it just hangs on the fifo?

Comment: What makes you think java is not invoked? The Java class will read the fifo or block if there's nothing to read

Comment: @g00se With multiple terminals to the same server, when running the command as described in one terminal, the command just hangs forever and I never see the java process start using the other terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
tail -f cmdline | /opt/jdk-18/bin/java ...
```